# How do I change how a specific file extension is called in the details pane with its own icon?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, icons, file-association

I want to change the info here (in the details pane):

[image]

I want it to say what the file is used for and what it's called, and in this instance, I want it named "NES Game ROM" (for example) instead of just "NES file".
For files with multiple uses, I want to designate a directory/set of files for which the BINs and MDs are called "Genesis ROM" and "Markdown Document".

How can I do this? I also see my PNG and JPEG images called "PNG/JPEG file" instead of "PNG/JPEG image" for some reason?

Also, how can I designate a specific filetype to have an icon for every file with its filetype matched?